# Chekout issue POST/rest/default/V1/carts/mine/set-payment-information-and-get-totals 400

Tags: checkout, magento2.4.2

I have an issue in checkout. It will make me crazy... The last days i try to understand why is happened.
When a customer is registered and go to checkout the issue is

```
POST https://mysite/rest/default/V1/carts/mine/set-payment-information-and-get-totals 400 main.js?attr=9IDcL1d…Qz3N6ZuKrKVk6g:2666
xhrSendProcessor    @   main.js?attr=9IDcL1d…Qz3N6ZuKrKVk6g:2666
window.XMLHttpRequest.send  @   main.js?attr=9IDcL1d…Qz3N6ZuKrKVk6g:2557
send    @   jquery.js:10260
ajax    @   jquery.js:9744
post    @   storage.js:46
(anonymous) @   set-payment-and-update-totals.js:32
(anonymous) @   cash-on-delivery-fee.js:26
notifySubscribers   @   knockout.js:1320
valueHasMutated @   knockout.js:1538
observable  @   knockout.js:1504
(anonymous) @   select-payment-method.js:20
_super  @   wrapper.js:73
(anonymous) @   select-payment-method-mixin.js:20
(anonymous) @   wrapper.js:78
selectPaymentMethod @   default.js:176
(anonymous) @   knockout.js:4245
dispatch    @   jquery.js:5232
elemData.handle @   jquery.js:4884


POST https://mysite/rest/default/V1/carts/mine/set-payment-information 400 main.js?attr=9IDcL1d…Qz3N6ZuKrKVk6g:2666 
xhrSendProcessor    @   main.js?attr=9IDcL1d…Qz3N6ZuKrKVk6g:2666
window.XMLHttpRequest.send  @   main.js?attr=9IDcL1d…Qz3N6ZuKrKVk6g:2557
send    @   jquery.js:10260
ajax    @   jquery.js:9744
post    @   storage.js:46
(anonymous) @   set-payment-information-extended.js:73
(anonymous) @   select-payment-method-mixin.js:27
(anonymous) @   wrapper.js:78
selectPaymentMethod @   default.js:176
(anonymous) @   knockout.js:4245
dispatch    @   jquery.js:5232
elemData.handle @   jquery.js:4884
```

I try to disable all extensions in checkout but with no luck
My first thought is that could be an issue from cookies...

Guest user place order without problem, Registred user have this issue and when they click Place Order they redirect to cart

How can i find or solve this? Had anyone face it?

I Request Payload (set-payment-information-and-get-totals)
for guest user

```
{cartId: "dxJXdNDj7P2PLpF7puxeFGwRcrKOlAjX",…}
billingAddress: {countryId: "GR", regionId: "489", regionCode: "AT", region: "Αττικής", street: ["test"], company: "",…}
city: "test"
company: ""
countryId: "GR"
firstname: "test"
lastname: "test"
postcode: "12345"
region: "Αττικής"
regionCode: "AT"
regionId: "489"
saveInAddressBook: null
street: ["test"]
telephone: "3213213213"
cartId: "dxJXdNDj7P2PLpF7puxeFGwRcrKOlAjX"
email: "mail@gmail.com"
```

for registered user

```
{cartId: "4913",…}
billingAddress: {customerAddressId: "114", countryId: "GR", regionId: "489", regionCode: "AT", region: "Αττικής",…}
city: "city"
company: null
countryId: "GR"
customAttributes: []
customerAddressId: "114"
customerId: "735"
fax: null
firstname: "name"
lastname: "lastname"
middlename: null
postcode: "172 37"
prefix: null
region: "region"
regionCode: "AT"
regionId: "489"
saveInAddressBook: null
street: ["street"]
suffix: null
telephone: "telephone"
vatId: null
cartId: "4913"
```

I See some questions for this but it isn't solved

I use Magento 2.4.2

Answer (score 1):

Having a similar issue after upgrading from 2.2.3 to 2.4.3.
I have an ancient no longer supported plugin for COD (msp cashondelivery) which causes a 500 error in checkout when selecting it as payment method. The fullscreen loader stucks in an infinite loop. I removed the loader element from object inspector in my browser so I can access the form again and the error disapperared when I checked the terms and conditions required field. So yes I can confirm that both a third parth plugin and the terms and conditions checkbox are BOTH related to similar errors (more specifically I have issue on /V1/carts/mine/selected-payment-method) as the author of this question stated at some point.

Comment: i remove the validator for cachondelivery and it work, i don't remember how i did it. As you say, if you don't ask for terms and conditions in checkout the issue disappear but i think it is not suit with GDPR

Answer (score 0):

4xx has something to do with Authorization.

Did you try open the `var/log` and `var/report` to check the error message?

Comment: i don't see any issue there for this issue, i only get an error for stats

```[2021-03-10 17:05:33] main.CRITICAL: Cannot gather stats! Warning!stat(): stat failed for /pub/static/frontend/Pearl/weltpixel_custom/el_GR/mage/requirejs/mixins.js {"exception":"[object] (Magento\\Framework\\Exception\\FileSystemException(code: 0): Cannot gather stats! Warning!stat(): stat failed for /pub/static/frontend/Pearl/weltpixel_custom/el_GR/mage/requirejs/mixins.js at /vendor/magento/framework/Filesystem/Driver/File.php:95)"} []```

Comment: How about you try it again? I often empty the whole folders. And then create the error, this way I always get the newest error.

If you still don't see any error in the var folder, you can open network tab, which is in your browser (chrome/firefox) devtool, this may help monitor the request and response. Maybe Magento will show log there.

Comment: i can't see anything for this in log folder again... 
from the network tab is the Request Payload i paste in the question.
When i simply click on the error i see ```<response>
<message>Request does not match any route.</message>
<trace/>
</response>```
In fresh magento installation i see that it call the ```/rest/default/V1/carts/mine/set-payment-information``` and not the ```/rest/default/V1/carts/mine/set-payment-information-and-get-totals```

Comment: That's weird, it should show the error.

Anyway, you can start debugging by opening the class handles the request, in this case, it is `\Magento\Checkout\Model\PaymentInformationManagement::savePaymentInformation`

Comment: is it a way to send you the link? maybe you can see something i don't

Comment: after search i find the if an paid extension is deactivated (extra fee in cash on delivery) this issue gone away.
Now when a register user try to place an order, he redirect to cart Request URL: https://mysite/checkout/onepage/success/
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 302

Comment: So I assume you found the problem now? Maybe contact the Extra Free vendor to get your support

Comment: Just crazy.... This issue comes from Terms and Conditions.

When i change in Terms -> Applied -> Automatically

checkout proccess works fine

 

But i don't have the terms checkbox in checkout page

 

Any idea to solve tis?

Comment: I think you need to find the root cause here. First you said it's about ExtraFee extension, then you think it's Agreement. These are 2 different things. So I suggest you dig into the code to find out the root cause.